# Routing using NodeJS and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am using NodeJS-Express-Jade-AngularJS, when i type in http:localhost:3000 i get my page which has table with a select button on each row. When the user clicks on corresponding row's select button i call a http get and pass in the selected row's ID as url string. My server returns me a new page but i don't know how to load that new page back in the browser

server.js code

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Home Page GET Request');  
  res.render('HomePage', { title: 'Demo App'});  
});
app.get('/id=:id', function (req, res) {  
  res.render('DetailPage', { title: 'Demo App'}); 
});
```

controller.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    var refresh = function() {
        $http.get('/HomePage').success(function(response) {
            $scope.list = response;
        });
    };

    refresh();

    $scope.select = function(id) {
        console.log(id);     
        $http.get('/id=' + id).success(function(response) {    
            // My response contains html code but how to display it in browser
        });      
    };
}]);
```

HomePage.jade

```
body
    .container(ng-controller='AppCtrl')
      h1 My List
      table.table
        thead
          tr
            th ID
            th Name
            th Action
            th  
        tbody
          tr(ng-repeat='contact in contactlist')
            td {{contact.Id}}
            td {{contact.Name}}
            td
              button.btn.btn-info(ng-click='select(contact.Id)') Select
```

DetailPage.jade

```
html(ng-app='myApp')


head
    // Latest compiled and minified CSS
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    // Optional theme
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
    title!= title
  body    
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading
        h3.panel-title!= Paneltitle
      .panel-body
        | Panel content
    script(src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js')  
    script(src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-route.min.js')     
    script(src='/controllers/controller.js')
```

Comment: what do you mean you don't know how to load the new page into the browser? I'm assuming that you mean your server renders `DetailPage.jade`, but you didn't list the contents of that page in the question....

Comment: for that matter, why would you make an `$http.get` request for an HTML page instead of using `a href=`?

Comment: Thanks that worked with a href, also i was wrongly calling $location.path('/id=' + id); after calling $http.get. I removed the get request and called $location.path('/id=' + id); in the select method